# State Monad: Modifying state without modifying value

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I am writing a function that takes a predicate `p` and a list. It 
returns `([value],[state])` where the first list contains elements that pass `p` and the second contains the elements that do not. However, when I run

```
runState (myFunc even [1,2,3,4,5]) []
```

I get `([2,4,5,3,1],[5,3,1])` where the failed elements are incorrectly being stored in `[value]`. I believe this is due to `get` updating both state and value, but I haven't been able to find a way to update just the state and leave the value alone so I was wondering how I would do that.

```
myFunc :: (a->Bool) -> [a] -> State [a] [a]
myFunc _ [] = do
  a <- get
  return a
myFunc p (x:xs) = do
    if (p x) then do
      s <- myFunc p xs
      let ret = (x:s)
      return ret
    else do
      s <- get
      put(x:s)
      myFunc p xs
```

Comment: I fixed some code alignment issues to make your example compile - feel free to revert them if they are not to your liking!

Comment: Your base case is the problem. Also, your function doesn't return `([value],[state])` it returns `State [a] [a]`. However, should you want to change that, that would _also_ be in the base case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `myFunc _ []` definition is indeed putting the state into the value. You actually just want it to be an empty list of passes:

```
myFunc _ [] = return []
```

and then you probably want to return the results in order:

```
myFunc :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> State [a] [a]
myFunc _ [] = return []
myFunc p (x:xs) = do
    passes <- myFunc p xs

    if p x then
        return (x:passes)
    else do
        modify (x:)
        return passes
```

side cool way to write it even though it’s probably an exercise in state and [`partition`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:partition) already exists,

```
import Data.Bifunctor

partition f = foldr m ([], [])
    where m x = (if f x then first else second) (x:)
```

Comment: I know it doesn't matter, but I recommend importing `first` from `Data.Bifunctor` instead of `Control.Arrow`. A relatively new Haskell user is more likely to understand what a `Bifunctor` is than what an `Arrow` is.

Comment: @dfeuer Good call.